# Why does Blockchain.com service gets stopped after a time?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, server, services

I've installed Blockchain.com local machine on our server and ran its service using the command below:

```
blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000
```

It works well, but after an unknown time, it seems that service gets stopped and I have to execute the command above again to be able to call APIs. Do you know what is the reason? Is there any limit on being that service active? And finally, do you have any special solution to make this service active all the time?

Comment: Have you checked the system logs?

Comment: What kind of log do you mean? And where is located? My server OS is CentOS 7

Comment: `/var/log/messages` and maybe `/var/log/secure`

Comment: Nothing special